In Vue, my node server.js works and connects with the table but axio doesn't
I'm following this tutorial Vue, Node JS, Express, MySQL Crud and this one Vue 3 Crud.
I'm trying to connect to my 'event' table, and this is my server.js file
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8081"
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Welcome to my app." });
});

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});

const db = require("./app/models");

const EventController = require("./app/controllers/event.controller");

EventController.create({
  event_name: "Espresso",
  event_date: "2024-02-16",
  event_desc: "Mf",
})

When I run server.js using node server.js, it actually manages to create the "Espresso" insertion to the event table. But in the vue project (where the server.js file is also located), I'm using 'EventDataService.js' for the crud methods. Here is EventDataService.js:
import http from "../http-common";

class EventDataService {
  getAll() {
    return http.get("/event");
  }

  get(event_id) {
    return http.get(`/event/${event_id}`);
  }

  create(data) {
    return http.post("/event", data);
  }

  update(event_id, data) {
    return http.put(`/event/${event_id}`, data);
  }

  delete(event_id) {
    return http.delete(`/event/${event_id}`);
  }

  deleteAll() {
    return http.delete(`/event`);
  }

  findByTitle(event_name) {
    return http.get(`/event?event_name=${event_name}`);
  }
}

export default new EventDataService();

And the http import is this http-common.js file:
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/api",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  }
});

This is how I'm using the code in my vue file:
import EventDataService from '../services/EventDataService'

and further down
saveEvent() {
            if (this.event_name == ""){
              this.titleWarning = true;
            } else if (this.event_date == null){
              this.dateWarning = true;
            } else {
                var event_data = {
                    event_name: this.event_name,
                    event_date: this.event_date,
                    event_desc: this.event_desc,
                };
                EventDataService.create(event_data)
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.event_id = response.data.event_id;
                        console.log("Successful");
                        console.log("Event ID: " + this.event_id);
                    })
                    .catch((e) => {
                        console.log("Error saving event to db: ")
                        console.log(e);
                    })
                    this.$router.push('/');
            }
        },

I getting an error (trimmed, let me know if I should give the full one):
Error saving event to db: 
message: "Network Error", name: "AxiosError", code: "ERR_NETWORK", config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest }
​
code: "ERR_NETWORK"
config: Object { timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN", … }
adapter: Array(3) [ "xhr", "http", "fetch" ]
baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/api"

I'm a beginner with this so I really don't know what I'm doing wrong - it may be the baseURL but maybe I'm missing the steps when using the . I'm using XAMPP for the database. Here are the dependencies of the project if necessary:
"dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "5.9.55",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "mysql2": "^3.10.1",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "sequelize": "^6.37.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vuetify": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "webfontloader": "^1.0.0"
  }

Anything helps, because I really don't know. Let me know if I need to give more codes from the project. Also, I'm wondering if I could just use the server.js file but it's in the root directory so i don't know how to import it on my src > components > Events.vue file

I think you are missing some code in your server.js file.
There should be some code to map routes before the app.listen() function.
It should be something like this:
...

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post("/event", (req, res) => {
  EventController.create({
  event_name: "Espresso",
  event_date: "2024-02-16",
  event_desc: "Mf",
  });
});

// Alternatively u could do it like this
// if your controller has functions with the correct parameters
app.post("/event", EventController.login);

// simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Welcome to my app." });
});

...


What this code does is create an endpoint in your backend with the route http://localhost:8081/event. The http.post('/event', data) in your frontend Vue application will send a request to that endpoint. You have to manually specify your URLs in your backend for every function in your EventController.

Thank you! But I still don't know how I'd actually use this in the vue component

Oh my god, I get it now. I need to run my backend and front end at the same time lol, and I need to define the routes in my backend. I'll keep trying

Yes, the frontend and backend are separate things. Id take a look at some articles that explain frontend and backend and HTTP requests to get some better understanding. Good luck tho!
